# Good online resource for common databases / open databases?

Tags: sql, opendata

I am trying to find the best area to download SQL tables of common subjects like states, countries, zip codes. Maybe even public/government information like FDA or FCC information.
Does such a resource exist and is it mature?

Answer (score 2):

geonames.org is a pretty good source of such data

Answer (score 1):

For states/provinces and countries, I'd recommend [ISO 3166](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166).

It's available [directly from the ISO board](http://www.iso.org/iso/iso_catalogue/catalogue_tc/catalogue_detail.htm?csnumber=46123) in PDF, but can be found online elsewhere.